# In JPA why and how to use insertable and updatable parameter?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

```
@JoinColumn(name = "", referencedColumnName = "", insertable = false, updatable = false)
```

Why `insertable = false, updatable = false` are required while using JPA for creating table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These two parameters are not required. You use them when you want JPA to prevent inserts and updates for a specific field.

Here is the relevant spec - [`@JoinColumn`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html).